# Composition of Binary Relations

Tags: relations

In Jech's Intro. to Set Theory Problem 2.3 f

$R^{-1}[R[A]] \supseteq A \cap dom R $.
Can I say that $R^{-1}[R] $ should be the identity relation and hence the above simplifies to $A \supseteq A \cap dom R$ which is true.

Comment: $R^{-1}[R]$ _contains_ the identity relation. It doesn't have to be equal to the identity relation. See exercise $2.4(e)$.

Comment: yes just saw that question thanks for pointing that out

Comment: But exercise $2.3(f)$ is straightforward. Take an element $a \in A \cap \text{ dom } R$, and show that it's in $R^{-1}[R[A]]$.

Comment: yes I didn't know that that was the method I needed to follow, had to look at a solution for that